# Style ASP.NET Drop-Down List with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have tried to style my dropdown list using bootstrap but have no idea why nothing has changed when I run the web.

This is my code:

```
    //aspx file
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" Width="136px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="selectpicker">  


//JavaScript file
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#DropDownList).click(function () {
        var str = "";
        $("#DropDownList:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
        });
        alert(str);
    });
});
```

Appreciate if someone can help me on this/recommend me ways to style the dropdownlist, thanks.

Comment: Changing dropdown list look and feel is that what you are looking for?

Comment: hi @Suprabhat Biswal, yes you are right! :)

Comment: Add this in DOM ready`$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();`

Comment: hi @Suprabhat Biswal, may I know what's DOM?

Comment: Sorry, DOM ready is equal to document.ready. You need to place my shared code in `document.ready`.

Comment: Did you read this docs https://behigh.github.io/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/